# Cannot Install Service & Components in Angular

Tags: angular, npm

I am new to angular and I am trying to install a service and component to my project. Below is the error I am getting when I run `ng generate component articles` and `ng generate service articles`

> Error: dryRunSink.commit(...).ignoreElements is not a function
>   dryRunSink.commit(...).ignoreElements is not a function

Below is the result of the `ng --version` command

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.4
Node: 6.12.3
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.2.0
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms, http
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

@angular/cli: 1.6.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.38
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.25
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.48
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.4
@schematics/angular: 0.1.13
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.13
typescript: 2.6.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

I tried reinstalling angular cli but that didn't help. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9194

Comment: tried changing the schematics version. Didn't help.